# Move every 500 files in new directory

Tags: for, mkdir, move

I have a directory that contains 10,665 jpeg files.

I want to move 500 files to a new directory, and 500 to the next directory, etc.

The largest files must be moved first:
500-1 contains the  500 largest files, 500-2 the next largest 500 files, etc.

The reason I want to do this is that I want to give the JPEGs to someone and the file manager hangs because there are so many in one directory.

Comment: This question is not clear: what is a 500 file? What is the sorting about? what is part1 and part2?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I think they want to move the 500 largest (or smallest?) files to directory `part1`, then the next 500 to `part2` and so on?

Comment: Or do you want a) order the files by size, and then move every 500th file (files 1, 501, 1001, etc) to _part1_, 2, 502, 1002, ... to _part2_ ?

Comment: I think the OP wants to "split the directory content" in chunks of 500 files each, but with sortimg from largest to smallest (i.e. such that the first new subdirectory contains the 500 largest files, the next one the 500 largest among the remaining etc.).

Comment: TiTAN what have you tried so far?

Comment: @steeldriver I think many things also: the question seems to fill my head with ideas —only I don't exactly know what they are. You can speculate, I can speculate (I have too many speculations to be useful). Hence I ask.

Comment: There is nothing in the rational (last paragraph, that would necessitate the sorting largest to smallest).

Comment: @TiTAN  will you be able to describe more .. is your directory constantly flooded with file every minute

Comment: You could create a zip file or a tar file. Then, to the filemanager, that would be a single file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Linux-based system or other one using GNU `find` you can use a loop something like this

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%s\t%P\0' |
    sort -z -rn |
    (
        # x is max files per directory; d is directory number; k is file counter
        x=500 d=1 k=1
        while IFS=$'\t' read -r -d '' size path
        do
            printf "%d\t%d\t%s\n" $k $d "$path"    # File nr, Directory nr, Filename
            echo "##" mkdir -p "/path/to/dir-$d"
            echo "##" mv -f "$path" "/path/to/dir-$d/${path##*/}"

            [[ $((k++)) -ge $x ]] && { k=1; ((d++)); }    # Next directory
        done
    )
```

Remove `echo '##'` from the two action lines in the loop when you are sure that they are going to do what you want them to do. Comment out the `printf` if you don't need a status report of what's going where.